# How to import a bigsize shapefile in geoserver

Tags: shapefile, filesize, geoserver

I want to import a shapefile in geoserver.
Its size is 2.2GB.

I tryed to use QGIS plugin (Geoserver Explorer- QGIS: version 2.8.6 Wien) to import but I have an error "filesize would require zip64 extensions".

As well, I tryed directly to copy the shapefile on the directory of geoserver but it doesn't work (no error message but the shapefile is not copied)

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please load shape file into postgis database. After import into geoserver from postgis. Guide video import from postgis https://youtu.be/NSMM4pp1kmg

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I imported my shapefile into postgis. Then I succeded to import to GeoServer but I don't succeed to see my shapefile. When I try to open it with the OpenLayers of GeoServer, it's still white page with no error messages.
When I try to download it in png file, I receive this error: "This request used more time than allowed and has been forcefully stopped. Max rendering tie is 60s."

Answer (score 0):

Either use the GUI to load the shapefile (see the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/index.html)) as with any other datasource, or use the REST API as described [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html).